# Perl chomp doesn't remove the newline

Tags: perl, chomp

I want to read a string from a the first line in a file, then repeat it *n* repetitions in the console, where *n* is specified as the second line in the file.

Simple I think?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(INPUT, "input.txt");
chomp($text = <INPUT>);
chomp($repetitions = <INPUT>);
print $text x $repetitions;
```

Where `input.txt` is as follows

```
Hello
3
```

I expected the output to be

```
HelloHelloHello
```

But words are new line separated despite that [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) is used.

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

You may try it on the following Perl fiddle [CompileOnline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_perl_online.php)

The strange thing is that if the code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(INPUT, "input.txt");
chomp($text = <INPUT>);
print $text x 3;
```

It will work fine and displays

```
HelloHelloHello
```

Am I misunderstanding something, or is it a problem with the online compiler?

Comment: This looks like a problem with line endings...what platform are you working on?

Comment: what is `hexdump -C input.txt` and `perl -e 'print $/' | hexdump -C`?

Comment: I'm using an online Perl editor/compiler as mentioned in the initial post  http://www.compileonline.com/execute_perl_online.php

Comment: hexdump result is: 00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a 33                           |Hello..3|
00000008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have issues with line endings; `chomp` removes trailing char/string of `$/` from `$text` and that can vary depending on platform. You can however choose to remove from string any trailing white space using regex,

```
open(my $INPUT, "<", "input.txt");
my $text = <$INPUT>;
my $repetitions = <$INPUT>;

s/\s+\z// for $text, $repetitions;
print $text x $repetitions;
```

> I'm using an online Perl editor/compiler as mentioned in the initial post http://compileonline.com/execute_perl_online.php

The reason for your output is that string `Hello\rHello\rHello\r` is differently interpreted in html ([\r like line break](https://eval.in/146107)), while in console `\r` returns cursor to the beginning of the current line.

Comment: So the problem is in the platform, not the code. Sounds interesting ! +1 for the regex. I'll mark up and solved ! Thanks

Comment: This doesn't explain why `print $text x 3` works, but `print $text x $repetitions` doesn't

Comment: You are right @Borodin, this is still a pending question, so I'll remove the mark as answer flag until getting from the latter answers why it has this behavior.

Comment: @mpapec : what is `\z` ?

Comment: @mpapec: I don't understand what HTML has to do with this, but setting `$repetitions = "3\r"` produces the same result

Comment: @Borodin I guess mpapec mentioned HTML because the asker using an online Perl compiler.

Comment: @AshrafBashir Try to run your script on a shell, you will see a different behavior.

Comment: @mpapec why this isn't reproduced with `print $text x 3` ? i.e. Why this line of code works fine in the online Perl compiler meanwhile `print $text x $repetitions` doesn't work well ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir it's not about `$repetitions` vs `3` that makes the difference, but `$text` which in your first example ends with `\r` control char, and in the second it doesn't.

Comment: `print "has \\r\n" if $text =~ tr/\r//` to check whether $text contains special \r char.

Comment: It doesn't have special \r, I tried your example `print "has \\r\n" if $text =~ tr/\r//` and it prints nothing

Comment: Your proposed reason doesn't explain why `print $text x 3` result is `HelloHelloHello` , while `print $text x $repetitions` result is `Hello <newline> Hello <newline> Hello`